# Running multiple arrays in SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to run 3 arrays in my SAS code and input each value into the variables in the last array, however, each time I run this code, it only populates the CREVASC_age column. Please let me know any thoughts on how to populate each age variable, in the third array, using the matching variables in the other arrays.

```
    data Outc_adjust3; set Outc_adjust2;

    ARRAY outcvars{3} CABG MI CREVASC;

    ARRAY outcdys{3} CABGDY MIDY CREVASCDY;

    ARRAY outc_age{3} CABG_age MI_age CREVASC_age;

    Do I= 1 to 3;

        if outcvars{3} = 1 then outc_age{3} = ageatenroll + (outcdys(3)/365.25);

        else if outcvars{3} = 0 then do; 

           if EXTFLAG = 0 AND EXT2FLAG = 0 then outc_age{3} = AGE_WHIENDFU;

           if EXTFLAG = 1 AND EXT2FLAG = 0 then outc_age{3} = AGE_EXT1ENDFU;

           if EXT2FLAG = 1 AND EXT2MRC = 1 then outc_age{3} = age_endfu;

           if EXT2FLAG = 1 AND EXT2SRC = 1 then outc_age{3} = age_ext1endfu;

        end;
    end;

    run;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You hard coded `{3}` when you needed `{I}`.  That is why only the third variable of the array was being dealt with.

Change the `{3}` to `{I}` for all the array indexed references inside the loop.